# GKE load balancer can only be accessed from cloud shell

Tags: google-cloud-platform, load-balancing, google-kubernetes-engine

I created a MariaDB deployment and service using [bitnami/mariadb](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/mariadb) helm chart. Here's the service settings for the master pod:

```yaml
service:
  type: LoadBalancer
  port: 3306
  nodePort: ""
  clusterIP: ""
  loadBalancerIP: ""
  loadBalancerSourceRanges: []
  annotations: {}
```

After the helm chart is installed, a GCP LoadBalancer is created and I can get the external IP. I checked the load balancer firewall rules and the IP ranges is 0.0.0.0/0

I can access the load balancer from the cloud shell just fine, but when I try to access it from my laptop it just won't stop loading and eventually fails. Is there any way to let this load balancer be accessed from anywhere?

Thanks!

Update:

1. My company has a VPN that lives in a GCE VM. When I am connected to that VPN, I can access the load balancer.

Comment: Do you have a firewall rule to allow the access?

Comment: Do you have hierarchical firewall rule in your organizations?

Comment: @KoopaKiller yes the firewall rule exists and the source IP ranges is 0.0.0.0/0 so it should be accessible from anywhere

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere no I don't. The project is not under an organization folder (No organization)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out there's something wrong with my ISP. When I change to a different ISP it works perfectly. Thanks for the help!